# Does anything distribute over exponentiation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is there any function $f(x)$ for which $f(a^b) = f(a)^{f(b)}$, other than the constant or identity function?

Comment: Constant functions don't distribute over exponentiation.

Comment: @Nitrogen, $f(x) = 1$ does.